# How to combine these vba macros

Tags: excel, vba

i have a vba macro im using for a project.

```
    
   Sub Count_Rows_Specific_Data_0835()
 With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 2
End With
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
   Columns("aa:aJ").ColumnWidth = 27.5
   Columns("P:az").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
   Columns("p:az").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Dim r As Long
    Dim L As Long
    Dim N As Long
    Dim P As Long
    Dim O As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim F As Long
    Dim G As Long
    Dim col As Range, I As Long
    Dim E As Long
Dim q As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim M, range_1 As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim iRange As Range

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    'loop through each row from the used range
    For Each iRange In .Rows

        'check if the row contains a cell with a value
        If Application.CountA(iRange) > 0 Then

            'counts the number of rows non-empty Cells
            counter = counter + 1

        End If

    Next

End With
 
   Set range_1 = Range("J1").EntireColumn
    With range_1
    r = Worksheets("Default").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    a = Worksheets("DEFAULT").UsedRange.Resize(ColumnSize:=1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
    I = counter - r

    
    For L = 2 To counter
    If Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        Select Case Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "O")
            Case ChrW(&H2713):             N = N + 1

        End Select
    End If
Next L
For L = 2 To counter
    If Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False And Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "o") = ChrW(&H2713) Then
        Select Case Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, "F")
            Case "Approved":            M = M + 1
            Case "In Work":            O = O + 1
                Case "Canceled": P = P + 1
            Case "In Review": q = q + 1

        End Select
    End If
Next L
    End With
    
    
    
    Worksheets("default").Cells(counter + 2, "Ab") = N
    Worksheets("Default").Cells(counter + 1, "Ab") = "MSN 0835"
    Worksheets("default").Cells(counter + 2, "aa") = "To be incorporated"
    Worksheets("default").Cells(counter + 3, "aa") = "Approved"
    Worksheets("default").Cells(counter + 4, "aa") = "In work"
    Worksheets("default").Cells(counter + 5, "aa") = "Cancelled"
    Worksheets("default").Cells(counter + 6, "aa") = "In review"
    Worksheets("default").Cells(counter + 3, "Ab") = M
    Worksheets("default").Cells(counter + 4, "Ab") = O
       Worksheets("default").Cells(counter + 5, "Ab") = P
    Worksheets("default").Cells(counter + 6, "Ab") = q
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells("1", "c") = N
   

    

    End Sub
```

Basically, this macro will go into the excel worksheet, search for ticks from this certain column. If there is a tick there, it will be placed into the value of N. After that, this will look into another column, column F, to see if there is any approved, in work, canceled(yes i know its spelled wrongly) and in review,  which will then add onto another counter which will be displayed at the end.

currently the issue i have is very mild. I use this macro to search for ticks in a certain column only, and currently i need to combine it with others to search other columns for ticks. What i have currently is actually the same macro, repeated 12 times in order to find the values of the same variables of the column.

heres an example. I use this macro to find ticks in column o, which is only for MSN (manufacturer serial number) 0835. After finding the amount of ticks for MSN 0835, which only occurs in specifically column o, i will then scan column f to see if the cells contain in work, approved, canceled or in review and count the amount of times each shows up. I have the same exact macro for column P, which is for msn 1238. In this scenario, i have the same exact macro for a total of 12 columns, finding for different msns. Is there a way i can use to combine them?

PS. The only change these macros go through is that they are populating cells in a different column, from aa to al. The other only change is from

```
Worksheets("Default").Cells(counter + 1, "Ab") = "MSN 0835"
```

to

```
 Worksheets("Default").Cells(counter + 1, "Ac") = "MSN 1238"
```

here are the msns from left to right: 0835,1238,1250,1017,1195,1408,3504,2342,2737,2912,3749,0000

I've tried doing the same thing but with different values in the same macro, combining 2, doesnt work and crashed my excel at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Count Rows of Specific Data

**New Method (Procedure)**

```vb
Sub CountMsnsTEST()
    
    Const MsnCodesList As String _
        = "0835,1238,1250,1017,1195,1408,3504,2342,2737,2912,3749,0000"
    Const SourceColumnsList As String _
        = "O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z"
    Const DestinationColumnsList As String _
        = "AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM"
    
    Dim MsnCodes() As String: MsnCodes = Split(MsnCodesList, ",")
    Dim sColumns() As String: sColumns = Split(SourceColumnsList, ",")
    Dim dColumns() As String: dColumns = Split(DestinationColumnsList, ",")
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(MsnCodes)
        CountMsns MsnCodes(n), sColumns(n), dColumns(n)
    Next n

End Sub
```

**Necessary Modifications in Your Method (Procedure)**

```vb
Sub CountMsns( _
        ByVal MsnCode As String, _
        ByVal SourceColumn As String, _
        ByVal DestinationColumn As String)
 
' code...
 
    Select Case Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, SourceColumn)
 
' code...
    
    If Worksheets("Default").Rows(L).EntireRow.Hidden = False _
            And Worksheets("Default").Cells(L, SourceColumn) = ChrW(&H2713) Then
 
' code...

    With Worksheets("Default")
        .Cells(counter + 1, DestinationColumn) = "MSN " & MsnCode
        .Cells(counter + 2, DestinationColumn) = n
        .Cells(counter + 3, DestinationColumn) = M
        .Cells(counter + 4, DestinationColumn) = O
        .Cells(counter + 5, DestinationColumn) = P
        .Cells(counter + 6, DestinationColumn) = q
    End With
 
' code...
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @VBasic2008, i am very confused as to how does this code work? I tried inserting my codes in and it managed to get the only the count of the ticks. And the code sort of makes a staircase table instead of a rectangle one.

Comment: Never mind, i managed to get all the counters working. How do i solve this staircase issue though?

Comment: I don't know what your code exactly does. I just presented an idea on how to make it more flexible (readable, maintainable). If there is a staircase, then there is a place where a variable is incremented by one when it should not. So you need to locate it. It should be a simple fix. If you can't, best ask another question with the new code and add a detailed description and some screenshots.

Comment: Alright, i understand. Actually, there's only one issue i have, the rest works perfectly fine. the code prints using the last few lines of your code.

but this ends up making it print in a downwards staircase where for example, for the first MSN it prints at a1 to a6 whilst the 2nd msn prints from b7 to b12. I would like to make it so that it prints from a1 to a6 and b1 to b6. is there a way to make it as such? i will try to upload a sample of the excel sheet using screenshots later after work.

Comment: If you remove the `counter + ` occurrences from the last block of my code, you will obviously always write to rows 1 through 6. Try that.

Comment: Actually yeah that would work. But i need to form a table at the end of the range and the range for the sheet changes everyday. Thats why i used the counter. Is there anyway for this to work with a counter variable?

Comment: Never mind, i managed to get it working. I shifted the codes with the counter from the CountMsns sub to the countmsnstest sub, and it managed to form a table instead of the staircase at the bottom of my data. Thanks so much for the help, giving an upvote for everything!